# Updating a value of a PFObject - iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Im trying to make the `PFUser` be able to edit there `PFObject`value that they created.

Currently, the `PFUser` creates a `PFOBject` in the `ClientCreater` class:

```
-(IBAction)New:(id)sender
{
    PFObject *New = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"client"];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [New setObject:user.username forKey:@"username"];
    [New setObject:[[self Name] text] forKey:@"name"];
    [New setObject:[[self Team] text] forKey:@"team"];
    [New setObject:[[self Points] text] forKey:@"points"];
    [New setObject:[[self Height] text] forKey:@"height"];
    [New setObject:[[self Weight] text] forKey:@"weight"];
    [New setObject:[[self Position] text] forKey:@"position"];
    [New setObject:[[self Game] text] forKey:@"game"];
    [New setObject:[[self Hometown] text] forKey:@"hometown"];
    [New setObject:[[self Birthday] text] forKey:@"birthday"];
  //  [New setObject:[[self Bio] text] forKey:@"bio"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(PlayerImage.image, 0.8);
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", Name.text];
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
    [New setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

    [New saveInBackground];
    NSLog(@"Object Added");
}
```

This is me trying to retrieve the `PFObject` in the `viewDidLoad` of the `ClientEditController` class:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"client"];

    // BEFORE WE QUERY
       [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];


    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // Get your objects here

            [objectt objectForKey:@"user"];

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

In the .h I have declared this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) PFObject *objectt;
```

Then here I try to update the value of `name` for the `PFUser`:

```
-(IBAction)SaveObject:(id)sender
{

    [objectt setObject:Name.text forKey:@"name"];
    [objectt saveInBackground];

}
```

Comment: And you don't really explain the issue. It looks like you never set the relationship between the user and the client, so you can't look a client up from a user later.

Comment: Hmm, If you look at the code when the object is created the user is added to the PFObject. @Wain

Comment: Do I need: `PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    [quoteNew setACL:postACL];`? @Wain

Comment: you set the user name, but not the user that I can see..  then when you fetch, you get an array back but don't pull out the first result.

Comment: So how would I set the user? @Fosco

Comment: [myObject setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

Comment: What do I do after I Add the user? How do I retrieve their object? @Fosco

Comment: if you need to query the object later, it looks like you already have the query for that above.